# antd v3 create form not available

Tags: reactjs, laravel, visual-studio-code, antd, ant-design-pro

The code below is using antd v3,for the antd v4 the form.create() is already not available, I read the documentation,it shows to replace the form.create() by useform.I tried to put it in the code(the second code) but still not working. Hhow can I use useForm in the code?

```
import React from 'react'
import {Form, Input} from 'antd'

const EditableContext = React.createContext();

const EditableRow = ({ form, index, ...props }) => (
  <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
    <tr {...props} />
  </EditableContext.Provider>
);

export const EditableFormRow = Form.create()(EditableRow);

export class EditableCell extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editing: false,
  };

  toggleEdit = () => {
    const editing = !this.state.editing;
    this.setState({ editing }, () => {
      if (editing) {
        this.input.focus();
      }
    });
  };

  save = e => {
    const { record, handleSave } = this.props;
    this.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
      if (error && error[e.currentTarget.id]) {
        return;
      }
      this.toggleEdit();
      handleSave({ ...record, ...values });
    });
  };
}
```

The useForm code

```
export const EditableFormRow = () => {
    const { form, index, ...props } = useForm();
      return (
        <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
          <tr {...props} />
        </EditableContext.Provider>
      )
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

useForm() return array, you can get form like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  return <>{["a@x.com", "b@x.com"].map((email) => EditRow({ email }))}</>;
};

const layout = {
  labelCol: { span: 8 },
  wrapperCol: { span: 16 }
};
const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: { offset: 8, span: 16 }
};

const EditRow = ({ email }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };
  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(form.getFieldValue("email"));
  };
  return (
    <Form form={form} layout={layout} onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item
        name="email"
        label="email"
        rules={[{ required: true }]}
        initialValue={email}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={onClick}>getFieldValue</Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: `export const EditableFormRow = () => { 
     const [form] = Form.useForm();
      return (
        <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
          <tr {...props} />
        </EditableContext.Provider>
      )
    }; `
Is it like this? May I know where this one  const { form, index, ...props }  should be put?@2tuzi

Comment: useForm not avalible in antd v3. here is an example v4. https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-playground-forked-tty0f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @ 2tuzi ya, I am using antd v4,and I am confuse how to use it in my case. After read the example, I still not understand, I am very new to React and antd, do you mind tell me how to use it in my case?thank you